# Is it possible to calculate the sha256 or sha1 hash of AWS s3 object?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hash, aws-lambda

I am trying to calculate the has for a s3 object. My way of doing it is this:

```py
def get_from_s3(bucket, key):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.get_object(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=key
    )
    return response['Body']


file_to_extract_from = get_from_s3(bucket, object_name)
    for line in file_to_extract_from.iter_lines():
        md5.update(line)
        sha1.update(line)
        sha256.update(line)
```

However, for some reason my hashes differ from the ones I get when I use
`sha256sum lorem_ipsum.txt`. Am I doing something wrong in my way of calculating the hashes?

Comment: Are you trying to get MD5 of an Object in s3? What about Etag, your calculated hash should match with ETag of that object

Comment: Correct. For some reason it didn't match though. I found out that it was just a problem with my makefile, where the lambda function wasn't being properly updated to the newest version so the hash calculation was indeed wrong